# convert into 8bbp pixel format

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, bitmap

How to convert resulted thresolded image in picturebox to 8bbp pixel format? I tried this code, but it not worked?

```
Bitmap orig = new Bitmap(thresholded);
            Bitmap clone = new Bitmap(width , height , System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed );

            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(orig);
            graphics.DrawImage(clone, 0, 0);
```

I'm getting a black picturebox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Point originPoint = new Point(0,0);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(originPoint, pictureBox.Image.Size);
Bitmap bitImage = (Bitmap)pictureBox.Image;
Bitmap formattedImage = bitImage.Clone(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
pictureBox.Image = formattedImage;
```

The `formmattedImage` object contains what you're looking for, I'm putting it back into the `System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox` object I have on my form just to make it easier to see.